# Difference between Rails 'raise StandardError.new' and 'raise StandardError'

Tags: ruby

To handle Rails exceptions, I see people do 'raise SomeException.new' or 'raise SomeException', what are the differences?

Say if I have a class

```
 class UnableToCreateShipments < StandardError; end
```

Can I do both?

```
raise UnableToCreateShipments
raise UnableToCreateShipments.new
```

Or with message

```
raise UnableToCreateShipments, 'my error message'
raise UnableToCreateShipments.new('my error message')
```

Comment: This is actually Ruby (the language) not Rails (the web framework).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do both, but Boris Batsov's Ruby Style Guide and RuboCop recommend the simpler version of just passing the exception class rather than creating an instance of it.